# Formatting populated textarea, carriage returns, newlines, and HAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, textarea, newline, haml, carriage-return

When i populate a textarea with text using \r\n (carriage return - newline) the text is formatted improperly [UPDATE: \r\n is what is generated when filling out a textarea, i'm simply pulling from a database what was previously filled in. Also to note, in the production environment i don't seem to have this problem. END UPDATE] For example:

```
%textarea  
  = "hello\r\nHow are you?"
```

comes out like this:

```
hello  
        How are you?
```

I'm thinking this might have something to do with HAML. Can anyone help me out? 
Note: if i use \n\r it works fine, but thats technically incorrect and id have to do some gsubs to reverse them for proper display.

Comment: Are there any spaces/carriage returns within the textarea tag?  E.g. `<textarea>   foo   </textarea>`.

Comment: Yes, when i view the source there is a bunch of space between the first and second part.

Comment: normally in strings you just use `"\n"` for a newline. Doesn't that work?

Comment: \r\n is just what gets submitted when someone fills out a textarea with line breaks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because Haml automatically indents the HTML source code, the contents of whitespace-sensitive tags like pre and textarea can get screwed up. The solution is to replace the newlines inside these tags with HTML newline entities `&#x000A;`, which Haml does using the `Haml::Helpers#preserve` and `Haml::Helpers#find_and_preserve` helpers.

Normally, Haml will do this for you automatically when you’re using a tag that needs it (this can be customized using the `:preserve` option). For example,

```
%p
  %textarea= "Foo\nBar"
```

will be compiled to

```
<p>
  <textarea>
Foo&#x000A;Bar</textarea>
</p>
```

However, if a helper is generating the tag, Haml can’t detect that and so you’ll have to call `Haml::Helpers#find_and_preserve` yourself. You can also use `~`, which is the same as `=` except that it automatically runs `find_and_preserve` on its input. For example:

```
%p= find_and_preserve "<textarea>Foo\nBar</textarea>"
```

is the same as

```
%p~ "<textarea>Foo\nBar</textarea>"
```

and renders

```
<p><textarea>Foo&#x000A;Bar</textarea></p>
```

Source: [this Haml FAQ](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#whitespace_preservation).

Comment: nex3, HUGE thanks! (can I hug you?) :D. `.gsub("\n",'&#x000A;').html_safe`

Comment: You can also use Rails' text_area helper: `= find_and_preserve f.text_area :title`

Comment: @thutt's answer is superior: use `~`, which is an alias for `= find_and_preserve...` instead of `=`

Answer (score 3):

Short answer if `= f.text_area :foo` displays unwanted white-space at each newline:

**replace `=` with `~`**

For a more detailed explanation for the reasons behind it, read [Natalie's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3073540/3449673) and the [HAML docs about ~](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#tilde).

Answer (score 2):

Continuing with @nex3's answer,  if you want to do some multi-line content inside a textarea, try it like this:

```
%textarea#textarea_id{:name => 'area_name'}
  :preserve
    Line1
    Line2
    Line3
    Line4
    Line5
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing

```
%textarea  
  = "hello\r\nHow are you?"
```

to

```
%textarea "hello\r\nHow are you?"
```

all on one line seems to have solved the problem. I guess that means it was a HAML issue.